# FileField not uploading_to directory (WEIRD SOLUTION)

Tags: django, file-upload

**EDIT**:  I decided to try uploading the photos to the media directory itself (upload_to='').  It worked.  Question still remains, why can't I upload to the next directory in the path? I've done it successfully on my local server and also remotely in the past.  WHAT GIVES?

This is a major problem right now and I can't figure out the issue.  I want to save images to the directory "post_photos".  On my local, windows environment, this works fine.  In the past, I've also gotten it to work just fine on Linux.  Right now, for some reason, my Ubuntu environment won't allowed uploaded files.

```
class Post_Photo(models.Model):
post=models.ForeignKey(Post,blank=True,null=True)
photo=models.FileField(upload_to="post_photos") 

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.post)
```

settings file

```
     MEDIA_ROOT = '/path_to_mysite/public_html/media'  ##i've also tried this with a trailing slash
```

On the command line, I've created the directory post_photos in media.  As per a tutorial, I chgrp to www-data (i think that's what apache is running as) and, then, chmod g+w.  I also tried to just chmod 777 for the directory.

In my admin, the post_photos are saving and it's showing me a path to the images...they just don't actually exist.

Has anyone come across this sort of problem?  Should I change the permissions of more directories?

When I try to upload a file in my admin backend, it gives me the following error:

```
Failed to load source for: http://(mysite.com)/admin/website/post_photo/4/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to end your `MEDIA_ROOT` with a `/`

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/path_to_mysite/public_html/media/'
```

**EDIT**

In addition, you need to specify the name of the file in upload_to. You can check out [the docs here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#filefield).

Comment: Sorry about that. Missed that you're not passing the file name info as well as the sub-directory.

Comment: Nope. The docs state `upload_to` must be the rest of the file name as in `upload_to="post_photos/photoname.jpg"`. You can create a callable which will programatically determine the name, or use Python's `strftime` stuff in the path. But it needs to be the entire name after the `MEDIA_ROOT` part.